# Can I buy a A320 FCOM, FCTM and QRG as non-pilot?

Tags: airbus

I am very interested in the Airbus Systems. I really like the FCOM of the A320, there are some of them on the internet.

However, I like holding physical books in my hands more, than reading them on a screen. But I don't have the paper nor the print color to print [more than 1000 pages](http://nicmosis.as.arizona.edu:8000/ECLIPSE_WEB/TSE2015/A320_DOCUMENTS/A320-FCOM_DSC%20Aircraft%20Systems_part2.pdf).

I would really like to buy a FCOM of the Airbus A320-Family. Can non-pilots, like me, buy a FCOM? If yes, where?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but can't you just let your local print shop print and bind it for you?

Comment: @Sanchises I calculated it. It would cost 40 € to s/w print the FCOM. Maybe I can get it cheaper.

Comment: Perhaps contact Airbus?

Comment: What Kevin said. What have you tried to do in order to answer your question yourself before posing it here? At least some of that information really should go into the question.

Comment: I'd guess that a local print shop cost of  40 € is probably going to be less than getting an official copy from Airbus. But that's just a guess... Have you asked them?

Comment: I would second @FreeMan suggestion, take the PDF to a print shop (like FedEx kinko's or any number of online services) and see what it costs to have one print and bound. They may have to bind it in volumes for you, but it should be much cheaper than trying to buy one from Airbus.

Comment: I thought about a website selling (used) FCOMs or something similar. Good idea to contact Airbus, I will do that.

Comment: @NoahKrasser I actually own 3 sets of airbus 320 FCOMS original prints with airbus binders and all, I also have soft copies. The reason it’s very difficult to find is that airbus update their manuals frequently and hard copies are kind of obsolete now...but if ur interested we can probably arrange something.

Comment: @OverD Thanks for your kind offer, but I wrote this question when I still was in school and I had more free time. I still love aviation, but don't have the time anymore. Thanks though.

Comment: @OverD do you still have original A320 FCOM? Old version with 4 volumes or new version with 6 volumes?

Comment: @Afe I have the old original FCOMS along with QRH that was given to me by my previous airline

Comment: What is the condition? Can we chat privately?

Comment: @Afe they are in great condition, they have not been updated since 2005. But the binders and all are all original